# Android PayPal SDK Receive Single Payment

Tags: android, paypal

I'm creating some Android apps that require a very small payment for $0.99 per magazine. I was looking to use Paypal as my payment method but my app keeps rejecting login in I read that is because is in testing sandbox and see this:

```
Upgrade your PayPal account as necessary
Before attempting to use a live app to directly accept credit cards, go to the Account Eligibility page. In order to use a live app to directly accept credit cards, you may need to sign up for PayPal Payments Pro (a paid subscription).

Additionally, please note that you must have a PayPal Business account to accept PayPal as a payment method.
```

Is necessary to Upgrade my personal account and pay monthly fees for in app purchasing? 
If so is there any other way to receive payments that doesn't cost monthly?I don't think this magazine app will do much money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Additionally, please note that you must have a PayPal Business account to accept PayPal as a payment method.

You need to do that and make your account business validated. Without verified business account you will not be able to go live with your app as you won't get production API access.

Comment: PayPal business account use monthly fees? Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: No. It's matter of verification of company behind the account.

Comment: Thanks for the help :]